# How do I override modules in requiejs?

Tags: node.js, requirejs

Just started using node with requirejs last night.

I want to substitute a module depending on a configuration parameter (say, passed in from the command line).

Right now, `moduleA` requires `moduleB`.  How can I overwrite `moduleB`, or substitute `moduleC` for it?

EDIT

**I'm using RequireJS.**

I really want a third party module, say `moduleMaster` to specify the update.  The goal is to allow multiple possible behaviors (ie multiple Database Access Objects, 1 per module) and then allow a master module to choose which one the other modules use.  Something like:

```
// module A
define(['B'], function(B) {
  console.log(B.msg);
});

// module B
define({
  msg: "I am B"
});

// module C
define({
  msg: "I am C"
});

// module D
define([], function() {
  // TODO: overwrite moduleA so that it uses moduleC instead
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as overwriting a module. What you can do is have RequireJS change what it loads depending on a configuration option. For instance,

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
var define = requirejs.define;

define('A', ['Adep'], function(Adep) {
  console.log(Adep.msg);
});

define('B', {
  msg: "I am B"
});

define('C', {
  msg: "I am C"
});

var make_A_depend_on = 'C';

requirejs.config({
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Adep': make_A_depend_on
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['A']);
```

If you change `make_A_depend_on` so that the value is `"B"` then `A` will load `B` rather than `C`. The configuration is set so that when the madule named `Adep` is required, RequireJS actually loads what is specified in `make_A_depend_on`.